# How to use variables created in gunicorn's server hooks?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I am using gunicorn to run my Flask application. I would like to register server hooks to perform some action at the start of the application and before shutting down, but I am confused on how to pass variables to these functions and how to extract variables created within them.

In gunicorn.conf.py:

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
workers = 2
loglevel = "info"
preload = True

def on_starting(server):
    # register some variables here
    print "Starting Flask application"

def on_exit(server):
    # perform some clean up tasks here using variables from the application
    print "Shutting down Flask application"
```

In app.py, the sample Flask application:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello', methods=['POST'])
def hello_world():
      return jsonify(message='Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9000, debug=False)
```

Running gunicorn like so: `$ gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py app:app`

Answer (score 8):

A bit late, but you have access to the flask application instance through `server.app.wsgi()`. It returns the same instance used by the workers (the one that is also returned by `flask.current_app`).

```
def on_exit(server):
    flask_app = server.app.wsgi()
    # do whatever with the flask app
```

Answer (score -1):

Put the data you need to pass to the hooks into environment variables.

You can also store the data to be passed to the hooks and from them in files.

Answer (score -3):

What are you trying to achieve is not possible due to the wsgi interface and the way the state is managed between requests.